# Auto adjust height of a div

Tags: jquery, css, height

I want to make a div with the height of the window but can the height be auto-upgradeable?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var hpd = $(document).height();
    var hph = $(".header").height();

    $('.wrapper').css({height: hpd })
    $('.contenido').css({height: hpd-hph-1 })

});
```

Comment: You can do this in CSS: `height: 100%`. Just make sure all parent elements have this set too. Also, what do you mean by `auto-upgradable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).resize(function(){
            $(".example").height ($(this).height());
     });
});
```